# Are there any incidents of war / brutalities because of Football match other than the famous one between El Salvador and Honduras?

Tags: war, sports, world

We all know that football is most popular game all over the world, And it has emotional big touch to it.  There are many weird incidents happened because of this wonderful game,

I am looking for significant **incidents i.e. war / rampages / brutalities**  those were recorded between football matches.

the famous one that I know is [FootBall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_War) War between  **El Salvador and Honduras**.

Comment: It seems implied by "war", but are you looking for incidents between nations over football, or just violent incidents in general? If the latter, football hooliganism is well documented: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_hooliganism

Comment: It was my understanding that "The football war" was actually economic rather than caused by a game of football?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the Football War you mention, the only instance I know of that a football game influenced an actual war is case #10 listed below, the 1990 Red Star vs. Dinamo game in Zagreb. Here is a list of ten games that featured violent outcomes:

1. 2012, Port Said-Cairo match in Egypt saw over 70 people killed accompanied by massive riots and burning down of the stadium and nearby buildings.
2. 1985 European Cup Final, Heysel Stadium, Brussels. Liverpool and Juventus fans fought a pitched battle resulting in 39 dead and over 350 injured.
3. In 2012, a match between FC Olympiakos and FC Panathinaikos in Greece featured a large riot in which the fans set the stadium on fire and injured 9 police.
4. At the 1974 UEFA Cup Final, Tottenham Hotspur vs Feyenoord, angry English fans rioted, doing significant damage to the stadium.
5. In 1985, Birmingham vs. Leeds a massive riot erupted resulting in property damage.
6. At the [Turkish League championship in Istanbul in 2012](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-18046286) Fenerbahce fans rioted and started setting fires in the stadium and in the vicinity. One man was seriously injured.
7. In 2013, the Czech Cup had to be postponed when the fans of opposing teams started a massive brawl and riot.
8. The [2003 Wrocław football riot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2003_Wroc%C5%82aw_football_riot) featured an armed battle between opposing fans in which one person was killed and dozens injured.
9. The famous [Kennilworth Road riot](http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/football/21446176) of 1985 occurred after a match between Millwall vs. Luton match in England. 47 people were injured.
10. In Zagreb in 1990 the match between Dinamo and Red Star turned into a violent brawl that ended in the stadium being torched. The event was considered a factor in the genesis of the Yugoslavian civil war that broke out the next year.

Comment: Actually, Hillborough wasn't caused by a riot. It was caused by poor management of the situation and over crowding, the pens in question had a maximum capacity of 2,200 (which should have been reduced to 1,600 for safety reasons) but the Police allowed in excess of 3,000 to enter the terrace pens. Most of the people who died were crushed to death due to the amount of people. [A recent inquest found that the police shifted the blame onto the supporters](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-merseyside-19577033). Blaming it on the supporters is actually considered pretty offensive over here.

Comment: @Kobunite I removed Hillsborough, as in any it was not a riot or fight, and should not have been in the list anyway.

Comment: There are those who blame the Port Said incident on the Egyptian government too.